# How to sort table of fetched data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sorting, html-table

I've created a table with data fetched from a server and I'm trying to sort it but have no idea how to access the certain data. For example how to sort the rows by selling price or number of watchers. What I usually saw was an object which was pretty easy to sort regarding an easy access to keys and values, but I am struggling with raw paths connecting my code with API. Here's a piece of code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      itemList: [],
    };
  }
  createTableItems = () => {
    const {loading, itemList} = this.state;
        
    return (
      itemList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index+1}>
            <td>{index+1}</td>
            <td 
              className="imgURL"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${item.galleryURL})`
              }}>
            </td>
            <td className="textToLeft">{item.title}</td>
            <td>{categoryItems}</td>
            <td>{ebayCategoryItems}</td>
            <td>{(Number(item.listingInfo[0].watchCount).toFixed(0)) >= 0 ? (Number(item.listingInfo[0].watchCount)) : 0}</td>
            <td>{(Number(item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__)).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>{item.shippingInfo[0].shippingType[0]!=="NotSpecified" ? (Number(item.shippingInfo[0].shippingServiceCost[0].__value__).toFixed(2)) : 0.01}</td>
            <td>{item.shippingInfo[0].shippingType[0]!=="NotSpecified" ? (Number(item.shippingInfo[0].shippingServiceCost[0].__value__) + Number(item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__)).toFixed(2) : (Number(item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__)).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>{item.sellingStatus[0].sellingState=="EndedWithSales" ? "Sold" : "Not"}</td>
            <td>{item.listingInfo[0].listingType=="FixedPrice" ? "Fixed" : "Bid"}</td>
            <td>{moment(item.listingInfo[0].endTime, moment.ISO_8601).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}</td>
            <td>{item.sellerInfo[0].sellerUserName}</td>
            <td><a href={"https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=" + item.itemId} target="_blank"><i className="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        );
      }
    ));      
  }
    
  render () { 
    const {loading} = this.state;     
      return (
        <table className="tableStyle" id="table-to-xls">
          <TableHeader 
              list={this.createTableItems()}
          />
          <TableItems list={this.createTableItems()}/>
          <TableFooter/>
      </table>
      );
  }
}


// TableHeader component

import React from 'react';

class TableHeader extends React.Component {

  render () {
    var itemList = this.props.list;
  
    return (
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Lp.</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Category eBay</th>
            <th>Watchers</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
            <th>Sum</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Seller</th>
            <th>Link</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    );
  };
};

export default TableHeader;

// Table body component 
import React from 'react';

class TableItems extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.props.list}
      </tbody>
    );
  };
};

export default TableItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run itemList.sort() before return itemList.map(), but seems to me that your problem is what to do inside the sort function because you need to do all these conditions to have the final value of each column.

First I recommend you to take a look at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if you area not sure how this function works.

Now to sort by watcher for example, you will do something like that

```
itemList.sort((a, b) => {
  const aWatchers = (Number(a.listingInfo[0].watchCount).toFixed(0)) >= 0 ? (Number(a.listingInfo[0].watchCount)) : 0
  const bWatchers = (Number(b.listingInfo[0].watchCount).toFixed(0)) >= 0 ? (Number(b.listingInfo[0].watchCount)) : 0
  if (a < b) {
    return -1
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return -1
  }
  return 0;
});
```

You prepare your data first and after that you can do the conditions to return;

If I misunderstood you problem, please let me know.